# Changing cloned input type in IE causes value property to be lost

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have some checkbox inputs that I display in a modal, with preset `value` attributes. Upon clicking "OK", I clone them, change their input types to `hidden`, and append them to a div in my document body. If I attempt to retrieve their values, jQuery returns a blank string from the `.val()` function, which to my understanding should just return the `value` property. Conversely, if I do no input type conversion.. (if I leave the type alone, remaining a checkbox), calling `.val()` on those appended inputs results in the correct value. Is there something I'm missing, or is perhaps a bug in IE? Shouldn't the `value` property's initial value be based on the value of the `value` attribute?

Works in only in Chrome, FF, Safari.. not IE

```
$selectedCheckboxes.clone().attr('type', 'hidden')
```

Fixes IE issue

```
$selectedCheckboxes.clone().attr('type', 'hidden').each(function(){ $(this).val($(this).attr('value')); })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft documentation says that you can't change the `type` property of an `input` element once it already has a type:

> "Retrieves or initially sets the type of input control represented by
>   the object."

Ref: [type property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534700%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The MDN reference doesn't even list the `type` property, so there is no specification for what happens if you try to change it. The documentation for input elements is divided into different types, suggesting that an element is not intended to change type.

Ref: [input type="checkbox"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/checkbox)

Instead of cloning the inputs and try to change their type, create new elements:

```
$selectedCheckboxes.map(function(i, e){
  return $('<input>', { type: 'hidden', name: e.name, value: e.value });
})
```